# Ansible blockinfile replace if there is another block instead of inserting the new

Tags: ansible

I try to insert 2 ansible blocks in the same file, but Ansible replace the first block with the second.

If I insert the next 2 blocks:

```
- name: Setup java environment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /home/{{ user }}/.bashrc
    block: |
      #Java path# 
      JAVA_HOME={{ java_home }}/

- name: Setup hadoop environment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /home/{{ user }}/.bashrc
    block: |
      #Hadooppath# 
      HADOOP_HOME={{ hadoop_home }}/
```

Only the second block will be in the file, becouse it replace the first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To insert 2 blocks with Ansible in the same file and don't replace the first with the second:

Change the Ansible blockinfile marker:

```
blockinfile_task_1:
marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK insertion 1"
blockinfile_task_2:
marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK insertion 2"
```

For the previous example, the playbook will be:

```
- name: Setup java environment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /home/{{ user }}/.bashrc
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK Java"
    block: |
      #Java path# 
      JAVA_HOME={{ java_home }}/

- name: Setup hadoop environment
  blockinfile:
    dest: /home/{{ user }}/.bashrc
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK Hadoop"
    block: |
      #Hadooppath# 
      HADOOP_HOME={{ hadoop_home }}/
```

Comment: ..or, better, use a `template`.

Comment: @tedder42 Yes thanks, but if I use a `template` it removes the previous bashrc of the server, maybe there are other things configured.

Comment: sure- but any time you choose to only partially include a file in your CM, you are risking a lot. You might consider putting it in /etc/bashrc anyhow.

Comment: @tedder42 is wrong, you can't use a template for this situation. Often you have to manage configuration files that are edited by things out of your control. So Ansible should behave reasonably in this case.